# Fixing an infinite loop in red-black tree deletion fix-up

Tags: go, debugging, tree, red-black-tree

I'm trying to implement a red-black tree. I have insertion working and have been trying to get deletion working for the past couple of days. I apologize for the poor variables names; I changed them to the generic "x, y, w, z" names to appropriately compare my code to CLRS pseudocode. Here's my code thus far:

```golang
// Delete takes a key, removes the node from the tree, and decrements the size of the tree.
// The function returns the key of the deleted node and an error, if there was one.
func (tree *RBT) Delete(key interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    z, err := tree.findNode(key)
    // node with key does not exist
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    nodeToDeleteKey := z.key()

    y := z
    originalColor := y.getColor()
    var x *Node
    if z.leftChild() == nil {
        x = z.rightChild()
        tree.replaceSubTree(z, z.rightChild())
    } else if z.rightChild() == nil {
        x = z.leftChild()
        tree.replaceSubTree(z, z.leftChild())
    } else {
        y = z.rightChild().subtreeMin()
        originalColor = y.getColor()
        x = y.rightChild()
        if y.getParent() == z {
            x.setParent(y)
        } else {
            tree.replaceSubTree(y, y.rightChild())
            y.setRightChild(z.rightChild())
            y.rightChild().setParent(y)
        }
        tree.replaceSubTree(z, y)
        y.setLeftChild(z.leftChild())
        y.leftChild().setParent(y)
        y.setColor(z.getColor())
    }

    if originalColor == BLACK {
        tree.deleteFixup(x)
    }
    tree.setSize(tree.Size() - 1)

    return nodeToDeleteKey, nil
}
```

```golang
// replaceSubTree replaces one subtree as a child of its parent with
// another subtree. When replaceSubTree replaces the subtree rooted at node u with
// the subtree rooted at node v, node u’s parent becomes node v’s parent, and u’s
// parent ends up having as its appropriate child.
func (tree *RBT) replaceSubTree(toDelete *Node, replacement *Node) {
    switch {
    case toDelete == tree.Root():
        tree.setRoot(replacement)
    case toDelete == toDelete.getParent().leftChild(): // node to delete is left child
        toDelete.getParent().setLeftChild(replacement)
    default: // node to delete is right child
        toDelete.getParent().setRightChild(replacement)
    }
    replacement.setParent(toDelete.getParent())
}
```

```golang
// deleteFixup maintains the invariants of the red-black tree after deletion.
func (tree *RBT) deleteFixup(x *Node) {
    for x != tree.Root() && x.getColor() == BLACK {
        switch {
        case x == x.getParent().leftChild():
            w := x.getParent().rightChild()
            if w.getColor() == RED {
                w.recolor()
                x.getParent().setColor(RED)
                tree.leftRotate(x.getParent())
                w = x.getParent().rightChild()
            }
            if w.leftChild().getColor() == BLACK && w.rightChild().getColor() == BLACK {
                w.setColor(RED)
                x = x.getParent()
            } else {
                if w.rightChild().getColor() == BLACK {
                    w.leftChild().setColor(BLACK)
                    w.setColor(RED)
                    tree.rightRotate(w)
                    w = x.getParent().rightChild()
                }
                w.setColor(x.getParent().getColor())
                x.getParent().setColor(BLACK)
                w.rightChild().setColor(BLACK)
                tree.leftRotate(x.getParent())
                x = tree.Root()
            }
        default:
            w := x.getParent().leftChild()
            if w.getColor() == RED {
                w.recolor()
                x.getParent().setColor(RED)
                tree.rightRotate(x.getParent())
                w = x.getParent().leftChild()
            }
            if w.rightChild().getColor() == BLACK && w.leftChild().getColor() == BLACK {
                w.setColor(RED)
                x = x.getParent()
            } else {
                if w.leftChild().getColor() == BLACK {
                    w.rightChild().setColor(BLACK)
                    w.setColor(RED)
                    tree.leftRotate(w)
                    w = x.getParent().leftChild()
                }
                w.setColor(x.getParent().getColor())
                x.getParent().setColor(BLACK)
                w.leftChild().setColor(BLACK)
                tree.rightRotate(x.getParent())
                x = tree.Root()
            }
        }
    }
    x.setColor(BLACK)
}
```

I'm running into an issue where I hit an infinite loop in deleteFixup(). I've [attached a screenshot of debugging that shows current variable values in deleteFixup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtmhx.png).

The issue arises when I pass in a nil node (x) to deleteFixup()... I believe it's in this if/else condition in Delete() where x is being assigned to nil:

```golang
    if z.leftChild() == nil {
        x = z.rightChild()
        tree.replaceSubTree(z, z.rightChild())
    } else if z.rightChild() == nil {
        x = z.leftChild()
        tree.replaceSubTree(z, z.leftChild())
    }
```

The if / else if checks for the node to delete's (z's) right and left children and whether they're null or not. But sometimes, both the node to delete's (z's) right **and** left children are null, and x gets set to a null value regardless. Thus, when I pass x into deleteFixup(), the loop never breaks and I get stuck in this logic:

```golang
if w.leftChild().getColor() == BLACK && w.rightChild().getColor() == BLACK {
                w.setColor(RED)
                x = x.getParent()
            }
```

Can anyone help me figure out where in my code I'm going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You have not shown the function getColor() and that is important

Answer (score 0):

*But sometimes, both the node to delete's (z's) right and left children are null*

Which you would expect. If the node in question to delete is a leaf node and it is black, it won't have any children. Also in such cases, while w exists (the sibling), the sibling's children may not exist.